# use Table dataset field value in main report

Tags: jasper-reports

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestingImage" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="5470e3fc-1c9c-4841-8814-e3a935fa6684"> <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/><property name="ireport.x" value="0"/><property name="ireport.y" value="229"/><style name="table"><box><pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/></box></style><style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF"><box><pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/></box></style><style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF"><box><pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/></box></style><style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF"><box><pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/></box></style><style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF"><box><pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/><topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/><leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/><bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/<rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/></box></style><style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF"><box><pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<subDataset name="ImageDemoDataset" uuid="47414685-b792-4a30-9b14-fc32127ad3cc">
    <parameter name="lastname" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{picture}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="firstname" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstname}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="firstname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="lastname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="phone_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="picture" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="imagePath" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{picture}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="ImageDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<variable name="varImage" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None"/>
<detail>
    <band height="364" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="18" y="0" width="474" height="216" uuid="771aa5d8-1470-4fd9-b062-a913b6014f19">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value=""/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="ImageDemoDataset" uuid="c4a063af-d8d1-41c4-98bf-660a9eab651e">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ImageDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <returnValue fromVariable="imagePath" toVariable="varImage"/>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="70" uuid="6aa96500-79ab-4b8b-aa5f-0c9dbc22638f">
                    <jr:detailCell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="9528bbd1-627c-424c-a3f0-872f92799c94"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="90" uuid="ba88fb55-d423-4d1e-99a1-b81c44f6e65a">
                    <jr:detailCell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="5c85fd56-54ba-4d22-a3e4-adcdbbbc2b4f"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="8"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastname} ]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="100" uuid="29524685-b68a-4906-be22-50b0acacba7d">
                    <jr:detailCell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="9dacce68-21ca-4bcc-b9cb-bad1b3661611"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="94" uuid="4bb9635f-4173-4c5b-95ce-5a12a2332ea1">
                    <jr:detailCell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="94" height="30" uuid="8c6c58b1-d3fd-4fad-995a-caaaea6afe8e"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phone_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="100" uuid="b500de9f-6abf-41b8-9e5d-d408b94d32ce">
                    <jr:detailCell height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="0e6a1e56-974f-41a3-af08-0cf5b832b573"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{picture}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
        <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle">
            <reportElement x="48" y="266" width="100" height="98" uuid="290e1eb9-3a18-4a65-93d4-d155b98ce964">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$V{varImage}.equalsIgnoreCase("null")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\jigpra\\Pictures\\"+$V{varImage}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="48" y="231" width="100" height="20" uuid="32fd136d-d7c4-4256-be6c-e9ad7d5f7592"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[$V{varImage}]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
```

I want to use Table dataset Field/parameter in Main report. I added data of collection in table to show upin this data I have one value is image for every column. I want to get that Image name (currently in  collection dataset I pass name of image).

How can I retrieve picture field name in main report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not see the image because it does not have the proper `Evaluation Time` - it needs to be `Band` in your case.

The `staticText` does not support such setting, you need to convert it to a `textField` and set the same for the `Evaluation Time` property.

But even with the above suggestions you would still see the last value from your `ImageDemoDataset` `subDataset`. It is fine if that is what you want.

But if you want to display an image for each record in your `subDataset`, you would have to do it inside the table. If spacing was the issue, you could create a `columnGroup` and place the image in the `groupFooter`, isolating it below your main data.

**EDIT**: It seems that what you want is actually simpler and should not involve variables. You just need to reiterate over the same data source.
This can be done in 2 ways:

(1). Using the original `ImageDataSource` parameter:

`<parameter name="ImageDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>`

have the table datasetRun's expression like so:

`<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ImageDataSource}.cloneDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>`

Then create a list component under the table, with the same `subDataset` you used for the table and the initial data source expression:

`<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ImageDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>`

and set its `Print Order` to `Horizontal` in the List tab from the list component properties. Make sure you also specify the `Cell Width` to be small enough to allow repeating items to flow horizontally.

Cloning the dataSource for the table will ensure that the table will not exhaust it, so that the list component will still be able to iterate over it.

(2). Instead of passing the `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` as a parameter, pass just the collection you created it with and have a parameter for that. This way you do not need to clone the dataSource anymore:

`<parameter name="ImageCollection" class="java.util.Collection"/>`

Then have the table datasetRun's expression like so:

`<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{ImageCollection})]]></dataSourceExpression>`

Then create a list with the same `subDataset` you used for the table and use the  `dataSourceExpression` from above. You should set up the list in the same way as in (1).

Comment: Hello @Narcis
Thanks for Advice,
in current code I mention that i pass image name in dataset field.
Currenlty i working for static path so just i need name of varibale/field of Table dataset in to main report.
I use Return value for table dataset but its not working .

Comment: In the first part of my answer(the first three paragraphs), I explain why it is not working in your case and how you could fix it. Did you even try that?

Comment: First i try demo for show image using String its working
Evaluation time of image is image/binary while your image time is blob.
in my case i directly use location of that image

First earlier i try to show image in table its working with this evaluation time  (which is really bad).but now i want to show this images in my main report.

Comment: in my code i user my field elements in variable to return while  dataset run but unfortunately its not working

Comment: There is no such thing as image/binary or blob values for `Evaluation Time` for elements in JasperReports. Also, it is unclear what is working, what is not working and in what circumstances - your comments are almost illegible due to poor use of punctuation marks.

Comment: Currently  i use report as Evaluation time as report .
as above description  i mean that while retrieving image from data base is data type will be blob .
in my case i use collection from java.after that i store collection data source in to main report parameter and later use in table data set to retrieve.i already get my image in  column field (Using image  name and location bring me image in column ).
but i want to add that image in main report how can i ?

Comment: I m new in ireport (JasperSoft).

i don't know all features of ireport (JasperSoft) or all funcaionalities.

Comment: What is the reason to have the image in the main report? Where would you want it placed? Would you want it displayed after each data row? A design mockup with the desired output would be more appropriate. Otherwise we are just guessing here.

Comment: in every column i have image .if i placed image over there i think this will not suitable.i want to display image after completed table element on main report i will show image below of table with their name which is in table

Comment: no Check this one data are temp.
i just want to show u how i want [link](http://imgur.com/Xa1lCj5)

Comment: The image you linked is still not relevant. In your table subDataset you have a `picture` field for each row. In the linked image you show 2 rows and only one image. What is the relation between a row in the table and the picture?

Comment: Here Check this one  [link](http://imgur.com/a/wS2l6).
as above show each column has picture column in that i get image name.
i want to show that image in my main report instead of group column